# How to index complex types into Edm.ComplexType with Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am indexing data into an Azure Search Index that is produced by a custom skill. This custom skill produces complex data which I want to preserve into the Azure Search Index.

Source data is coming from blob storage and I am constrained to using the REST API without a **very** solid argument for using the .NET SDK.

## Current code

The following is a brief rundown of what I currently have. I cannot change the index's field or the format of data produced by the endpoint used by the custom skill.

### Complex data

The following is an example of complex data produced by the custom skill (in the correct `value/recordId/etc.` format):

```
{
  "field1": 0.135412,
  "field2": 0.123513,
  "field3": 0.243655
}
```

### Custom skill

Here is the custom skill which creates said data:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
  "uri": "https://myfunction.azurewebsites.com/api,
  "httpHeaders": {},
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "timeout": "PT3M50S",
  "batchSize": 1,
  "degreeOfParallelism": 5,
  "name": "MySkill",
  "context": "/document/mycomplex
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "text",
      "source": "/document/content"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "field1",
      "targetName": "field1"
    },
    {
      "name": "field2",
      "targetName": "field2"
    },
    {
      "name": "field3",
      "targetName": "field3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have attempted several variations, notable using the ShaperSkill with each field as an input and the output `"targetName"` as `"mycomplex"` (with the appropriate context).

### Indexer

Here is the indexer's output field mapping for the skill:

```
{
  "sourceFieldName": "/document/mycomplex,
  "targetFieldName": "mycomplex"
}
```

I have tried several variations such as `"sourceFieldName": "/document/mycomplex/*`.

### Search index

And this is the targeted index field:

```
{
  "name": "mycomplex",
  "type": "Edm.ComplexType",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "field1",
      "type": "Edm.Double",
      "retrievable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "searchable": false
    },
    {
      "name": "field2",
      "type": "Edm.Double",
      "retrievable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "searchable": false
    },
    {
      "name": "field3",
      "type": "Edm.Double",
      "retrievable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "searchable": false
    }
  ]
}
```

## Result

My result is usually similar to `Could not map output field 'mycomplex' to search index. Check your indexer's 'outputFieldMappings' property.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a mistake with the context of your skill. Instead of setting the context to `/document/mycomplex`, can you try setting it to `/document`? You can then add a `ShaperSkill` with the context also set to `/document` and the output field being `mycomplex` to generate the expected complex type shape

Example skills:

```
"skills":
[
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
  "uri": "https://myfunction.azurewebsites.com/api,
  "httpHeaders": {},
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "timeout": "PT3M50S",
  "batchSize": 1,
  "degreeOfParallelism": 5,
  "name": "MySkill",
  "context": "/document"
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "text",
      "source": "/document/content"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "field1",
      "targetName": "field1"
    },
    {
      "name": "field2",
      "targetName": "field2"
    },
    {
      "name": "field3",
      "targetName": "field3"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ShaperSkill",
  "context": "/document",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "field1",
      "source": "/document/field1"
    },
    {
      "name": "field2",
      "source": "/document/field2"
    },
    {
      "name": "field3",
      "source": "/document/field3"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "output",
      "targetName": "mycomplex"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Please refer to the documentation on [shaper skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-shaper) for specifics.

Comment: That work. I had incorrectly assumed setting the context to a non-existent context (such as `/document/mycomplex`) would cause that context to be created.